# Python List within List - References

Tags: python, list

I had a look through the other answers but couldn't really find an answer to mine.

The program needs to return a persons age given their name.

```
    recordslist = [["Daniel", 18], ["John", 19], ["Paul", 20], ["Jack", 44]]

         def(name):



    checkAge(str(input("What is your name?")))
```

For example if Daniel is entered, the program returns 18.
If John is entered, the program returns 19.

I'm not sure how to code this. There must be a *for* and *in* command somewhere in that def.

Thanks :-)

Comment: you're using the wrong data type. Use a `dict` instead of a `list` of `lists`, like: `records = {"Daniel":18, "John":19"}` then do `records[name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for - `dict(recordslist)`. A [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python is a key value pair. Your data can be better structured as a key value pair. Key being the name of the person and value being his/her corresponding score. `dict(recordslist)` converts your data from a list of lists to a dictionary.

You can access the value corresponding to a key in a dictionary as:

```
dictionary_variable[key]
```

Demo:

```
>>> recordslist = [["Daniel", 18], ["John", 19], ["Paul", 20], ["Jack", 44]]
>>> a_dict = dict(recordslist)
>>> a_dict
{'John': 19, 'Paul': 20, 'Daniel': 18, 'Jack': 44}
>>> a_dict['Daniel']
18
```

In your code you would do:

```
def checkAge(name, a_dict):
    if name in a_dict:
        return a_dict[name]
    else:
        return "No score found for {}".format(name)

result = checkAge(str(input("What is your name?")))
print result
```

**Note:** In order for this to work as you expect it to, you must have unique names in your list of list. This is what I mean:

```
>>> recordslist = [["Daniel", 18], ["John", 19], ["Paul", 20], ["Jack", 44], ["Daniel", 40]]
>>> a_dict = dict(recordslist)
>>> a_dict
{'John': 19, 'Paul': 20, 'Daniel': 40, 'Jack': 44}
```

I added `["Daniel", 40]` to your `recordslist` and the `a_dict` has only one entry for `Daniel`.

Comment: Thanks, this answered things perfectly shak :-)

Comment: Hey Shak, I've just tried your code, and the program runs and asks for the name, but the program ends without displaying an age?

Comment: @DanielNitschke Are you calling the function and with the right parameters?

Comment: @DanielNitschke The function __returns__ the result. Shouldn't you be either getting it's result in a variable and printing it __OR__ printing the result in the `checkAge` method? Updated the answer to do so!

Comment: Heya, the old code should have just printed the return. I've adapted your new code, but am still receiving this parameter error:
result = checkAge(str(input("What is your name?")))
TypeError: checkAge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recordsdict'

Comment: Lol, I've just realised my mistake. I was only entering one parameter when running the program. I've solved it with: 

result = checkAge((str(input("What is your name?"))), recordsdict)
print(result)

Comment: Thanks for all your extended help Shak :-)

Answer (score 0):

As shaktimaan [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23073533/298607), a dict is the right data structure if you have unique names.

If you have multiple entries with the same name potentially, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> recordslist = [["Daniel", 18], ["John", 19], ["Paul", 20], ["Daniel", 22]]
>>> tgt="Daniel"
>>> [(name, age) for name, age in recordslist if name==tgt]
[('Daniel', 18), ('Daniel', 22)]
```